# Holiday Deals everyone!

Tags: deals

Looking to revive the deals question. I just upgraded Ableton Live to Suite and got some nice sound libraries from Precisionsound.

http://www.store.precisionsound.net/index.php  -  50% sale on all samplesets
http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2012/12/04/holiday-deals-for-musicians-2012/

What are you getting this holidays season? 
Any other deals you're aware of?

Answer (score 1):

http://designingsound.org/2012/12/holiday-sales/

Holiday sales post from designing sound.org
Definitely check out the Boom library's advent calendar of deals.
As for me, I recently made a bunch of Black Friday purchases from Waves.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full list of december special sound effect libraries: Blastwave FX, BBC, Sound Ideas 50% deals, Sounddogs, Hollywood Edge and my own 5.1 libraries.
Have a look: https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundlibraries_e.php?view=Specials-Deals-Sound-Effect-Libraries

Also my own libraries are reduced: https://www.soundeffects.ch/soundlibraries_e.php?view=Soundeffects.ch

I'm happy to help,

Best

Guido

Comment: You mean to tell me that Sound Ideas is actually selling them what what they should actually normally be sold at nowadays? ;)

Comment: This is not easy to answer. And you probably have never collected together a soundlibrary. In today's time, people expect to get everyting cheep or for free. I'm agree with you that things should not cost more than it's worth it. But this is a philosophical question: What is it worth for me or not. For example: I need to upgrade my ProTools system. It will cost me $8000. Expansive or not? 
Same to sound libraries. If you collect together a sound effects library, which contains a large amount of sounds, it is not possible to sell it for $50. If you have car records on it, and also, let's say...

Comment: ...atmospheres from vietnam, it costs you a lot of money to go there, make the records. I will not denounce anything, but there is a difference between 'hard to get' sounds and not so. Why are there no wind collections? Give me some forest atmospheres (no planes, no cars, no stupid people in the back), good recorded birds and also correct descibed, where are the thunderclaps?? It takes you endless houres of boring waiting, frustrating situations with no results in the end, lots of interference which ruins your records. This things are difficult to get, but you will find it for example on...

Comment: ...Hollywood Edge and also on Sound Ideas libraries, at Sounddogs, BBC and my own collections and others I forgot. If you like it or not is a personal thing, but everybody is invited to go out and make his own records - and see how difficult it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small thing, but Pro-sound is offering a 25$ gift to use in the rentals or service department.  Just mention the gift via pro sound newsletter/email from Richard Topham Jr.

Answer (score 0):

The Deals at Plugin Alliance are still going until Jan 1st:

https://plugin-alliance.com/en/xmasc.html?door=25